# Не загружается Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте, на моем `Lenovo Y50-70` перестала загружаться `Ubuntu 16.04 lts`.
На ноуте стоит две системы: `windows 10` & `Ubuntu 16.04 lts`.

При загрузке получаю сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опыт использования линукса только начинается.Буду рад любой подсказке)

Comment: так онже пишет чего хочет) а перед ошибкой чего делали??

Comment: Вот тут говорят, что проблема с дровами на wifi: https://askubuntu.com/questions/592191/error-during-startup-b43-phy0-unsupported-phy/676190

Comment: В том то и дело, что ничего, просто вебсерфил, потом выключил ноут, он ночь постоял, утром загрузил винду, и после этого перестало грузиться

Comment: WiFi у меня сразу не работал, у моего Ноута какие-то проблемы со встроенным адаптером, я пользуюсь внешним. Главное загрузиться)

Comment: удалось загрузиться, после того, как отключил автомонтиривание дисков винды в файле (/etc/fstab). Но это очень странно, неделю грузилось с тем файлом, что был.